# Can we have two different authentication styles and still achieve a SSO

Tags: azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, openid-connect, saml-2.0

Can we have two different authentication styles and still achieve a SSO?

My current application (Green) is authenticating using SAML against our AD.
My new cloud application (light blue) is using authentication using AAD using OpenID Connect

The AD is synchronised using AAD Connect to allow pass through authentication.

[image: Proposed SSO]